# Chronologically once a day merge columns of a CSV files using PHP

Tags: php, csv, merge, multiple-columns

Thanks is advance because I am new to PHP.  I have a csv file that I need to merge two columns and output to a new csv file once a day automatically.

Source file:  ONHAND.csv

> Group,Part Number,Free Stk
>   CAR,12129,1
>   SUP,1442,10
>   HUS,53111,203
>   VIS,4000414,3

Resulting file:  ALLIEDSTK.CSV

> SKU,QTY
>   CAR.12129,1
>   SUP.1442,10
>   HUS.53111,203
>   VIS.4000414,3.

Program notes:

1. Notice a period is added between the Group and Part Number values before the output to SKU.
2. I need to be able to set a time for this operation to run once a day.
3. I will need to change a specific Group value before the merge.
     Example source data:  CAR,12129,1
             resulting data:  MAG.12129,1

Comment: This site is not a free programming service. We're here to help you with PROBLEMS with your OWN CODE. So... show what you've done so far, and describe the problem you're having.

Comment: What have you tried and where are you stuck, I don't think SO is here to write code for you, but to help you to write the code.  That said things to look up are, CRON, fopen, fgetcsv, fputcsv. etc.